# Show loading icon before the execution of a function

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm trying to show a loading icon before execution of function but I don't have a clue how to do this.

My code:

```
$(".chartType").on("click", function(event){
    $("#wrapper").addClass("loading");      
    changeChartType($(this).attr("value"));     
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("loading");
});
```

It shows a loading icon (if removeClass() commented out) after the chart actually has been loaded. If someone knows a solution please let me now.

I've tried to use setTimeOut(), jQuery's when, then and done but nothing seems to work.

I'm using Google's visualization charts for displaying various charts. I've got the possibility to switch between charts by a click on a icon.

After that the function above will be executed.

The function changeChartType():

```
function changeChartType(typePar){
    chartType = typePar;
    chart = new google.visualization[chartType](chartDiv);
    drawChart();
}
```

And in drawChart it just calls chart.draw();
This takes a while and therefore I want to show a loading icon.

The problem is not about removing the loading icon but showing the loading icon by adding the class. Currently it adds the class after the chart has been drawn. Maybe there is a ay to synchronize this.

Comment: you can't if `changeChartType()` is asynchronous without modifying `changeChartType()`. Please provide what `changeChartType` does. Why do you use `$(this).attr("value")` rather than `$(this).val()` or `this.value`?

Comment: if you are change a `img`, you may use the `load()` function.

Comment: rookie mistake I guess, further info in a minute

Comment: I'm guessing `changeChartType()` is asynchronous ?

Comment: I guess it is. Otherwise it would work.

Answer (score 0):

All 3 of your functions are synchronous. That means they run one after another in very short amount of time.
Asynchronous functions take time and have callback, so you can do things after they finish.
For example:

```
$(".chartType").on("click", function(event){
   $("#wrapper").addClass("loading");      
   $("element").on("load",function(){
      $("#wrapper").removeClass("loading");
   });     
});
```

"removeClass" function will run after "element" is loaded.

Comment: Yes I know but the loading icon isn't there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper remove line running before changeChartType function has finished. Without being wrapped in some way to the preceeding function, the removeClass function will fire as soon as it's read, which may be before the preceding function has finished.

```
$(".chartType").on("click", function(event){
$("#wrapper").addClass("loading"); 
$.when( { changeChartType($(this).attr("value")) } ).done(
   $("#wrapper").removeClass("loading");
); });
```

I haven't tested this, but typos aside, the idea should work.

Here's a link for the when/done documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 0):

The `draw` method of the Google charts visualization API is asynchronous, which in turns makes your entire function chain async. What you will need to do is to listen to an event fired by all this mess and act accordingly. The event is defined and described [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events#The_Ready_Event).

In order for this to work, you will need to overhaul your code quite a bit. Here is the simplest way to do so:

```
$(".chartType").on("click", function(event){
   $("#wrapper").addClass("loading");
   var chart = new google.visualization[$(this).attr("value")](chartDiv);
   google.visualization.events.addListener(chartDiv, 'ready', function() { $("#wrapper").removeClass("loading") });
   chart.draw();
});
```

This *should* work, though it assumes that `chartDiv` is in the scope.

Comment: @MmynameStackflow: if it doesn't work - what does it fail on? Actually, could you build a fiddle from your current code so we can all have a go at fixing it?

Comment: The problem isn't about the removing part but the adding part.

Comment: @MmynameStackflow: the class is being added before the chart is even created. So either your chart is being generated so quickly that you do not see the loading icon, or you are not calling this function. Try putting a `return false;` after the addClass call,and see if you actually get the class.

Comment: I did that and the class is there. But after the chart has been rendered.

Comment: Obviously, you just prevented your chart from rendering (`return` halts the execution of a function and causes it to return). The question is...why is your chart being rendered if you're preventing it from rendering? For reference, you need to bind the event addListener **BEFORE** starting the generation of your chart.

Comment: I didn't use return but I commented out the removeClass function as I mentioned above. Because of this the loading icon is shown perfectly but it shows after the graph is rendered.

Comment: Where did I mention to comment out the `removeClass` call? I wrapped it in the Google event callback. That's not a comment.

Comment: Where did I mention that the loading class isn't removed properly? I just want the class to be ADDED before executing the function.

Comment: @MmynameStackflow: `addClass` is synchronous and the first call of that function. So, if it is not being added, or appearing after chart has been drawn, the problem **cannot** be in this function. This is why I (and everyone else, by the looks of it) assumed that this was the problem. Please build a fiddle so we can see what is the problem, as the problem **is not** in the code you've provided.

Comment: I don't have time to make a fiddle and it's to complicated in my case. But I think I know what the problem is. I think the creation of the chart has such an impact that the loading icon isn't working and doesn't even show. The loading icon stops spinning when I change chart type so it probably doesn't show for the same reason.